Xorg using 100% CPU when using certain programs
I recently installed Ubuntu 24.04 on my Computer. After setting it up I noticed that the CPU usage of Xorg goes up to 90 - 100% when I start notepad++ or a Python script. This results in the PC lagging and me not being able to use it it until I kill the Process.

Your computer specifications; name, model, amount of ram, and what kind of hard disks you have?
